# How to get Header and Footer from a different theme

Tags: xml, magento, magento-1.7

I have a custom theme (custom1) and I'm making another one (custom2). I need the new theme (custom2) to get the header and footer from the other one (custom1)... is it possible to do it via xml? If not what's the best way?
I was thinking to define the path in a **local.xml** or have a custom **page.xml** into (custom2) that gets files from (custom1) instead of base...

I've tried but nothing happens... probably, I'm declaring a wrong path or it's impossible to do it.

Comment: I don't think so, but why you need this ?

Comment: because I need a custom template (different from normals) to set once a while to some products to "highlight" them...

Answer (score -1):

I think you should just copy the custom1 template's code into custom2 template.  Should be simpler instead of dealing with xml file.